# What is "int i = 1;Why (i >= 60 * 60 * 1000 / 1 * 1000)" true?

Tags: c, type-conversion

First, defining two constant expressions without parentheses is my fault:

```
#define BIG_INTERVAL 60 * 60 * 1000
#define SMALL_INTERVAL 1 * 1000

int i = 1;

if (i >= BIG_INTERVAL / SMALL_INTERVAL - 1)
{
    printf("Oops!\n");
}
```

The `if` statement after the macro expansion is `if(i >= 60 * 60 * 1000 / 1 * 1000 - 1)`.

That is not my intention. But I find something strange if I write `if (i >= 3600000000 - 1)`. It is false.

What type is `60 * 60 * 1000 / 1 * 1000 - 1` ? `int`?

Comment: Please, change your Question Format.

Comment: And here we have the reason why sensible programmers do not use `#define` for constants.

Comment: @jalf: Or you could just remember to surround them with parentheses...

Comment: You could. In the same way that it's ok to shoot yourself in the foot if you make sure there's a doctor nearby? Why not just do it properly, and use an actual typed constant (say, a `static const int`, or perhaps an enum)?

Comment: @icktoofay: The problem is that parenthesis will fix this particular issue until you forget them, and even if you don't, you will run into a different issue with macros around the corner. There are just too many things to keep track of when you use macros. Consider this macro that was in one of the projects I worked: `#define for_all( iterator_t, it, container ) for ( iterator_t it = (container).begin(); it != (container).end(); ++it )`, that is used as: `for_all( std::vector<int>::const_iterator, it, v ) std::cout << *it;` simple... right?

Comment: @icktoofay: Now change the use to `for_all( child_iterator_t, it, x.get_children() ) std::cout << it->name(); ` and everything is nice and works as expected, right? Well, it does as long as `get_children` returns a *reference* to a container, if the code changes and the function returns a *copy* then you have undefined behavior. And the problem is that the macro is *hiding* the code. The problem is exactly the same as if you expand it in place, but the expansion is not visible. BTW, in the particular case above you can run into a segmentation fault, or worse: never entering the loop.

Comment: @jalf: Sensible programmers know the proper way to use #define for constants, but Celebi was using it for expressions, not constants. Anyway sensible programmers know how to do that too.

Comment: Retagged the question to "c". Your code is NOT c++; in c++ you should not be using printf() and #define's

Comment: @Andreas: please do not mistake good practices from standard. Both macros and printf have their usage in C++ and are valid.

Comment: @liori: yeah, but not in this case

Comment: @jalf: In C, unlike in C++, the name of an object declared as `static const int ANSWER = 42;` is not a constant expression, and can't be used as, for example, a case label.  One common trick is to use an enum: `enum { ANSWER = 42 };`, but (a) this is arguably an abuse of the `enum` keyword, and (b) it only works for values of type int.

Comment: @jalf `#define` constants also allow expressions to be computed at compile time if this behavior is supported by the compiler/preprocessor.  This translates to faster code as no lengthy load instructions are necessary.

Comment: @DavidCowden: a compiler written after 1960 would compute an expression like this at compile-time in any case.

Comment: @jalf Well, I know that inlining of functions defined in macros is still compiler dependent so I figure there might be some compiler that doesn't precompute constants.  If the OP were using floating point numbers modern compilers certainly differ in whether they precompute float values or not since the precision of floating point evaluation is heavily machine dependent.  Anyway, my point is that there *is* a sensible reason why a programmer might decide to use `#define` for constants.

Comment: @DavidCowden: you're comparing apples to oranges. A `#define` used in this way could be replaced by a single constant, it wouldn't need to be a function, inlined or otherwise. Apart from that, A `#define` is a single textual expansion. It does **not** guarantee evaluation of the expression at compile-time. Especially for floats, this would be the case, and a `#define` would do *nothing* to ensure compile-time evaluation. So if there is a sensible reason, you haven't yet mentioned it.

Comment: No I did mention it: "
@jalf #define constants also allow expressions to be computed at compile time if this behavior is supported by the compiler/preprocessor. This translates to faster code as no lengthy load instructions are necessary."

Comment: @DavidCowden: which is not true. No compiler has special support for "evaluating defines at compile-time". the expression is inserted into the translation unit, and the compiler then reads the resulting translation unit, sees an expression that can be (but doesn't have to be) evaluated at compile-time, and hopefully optimizes it. Which is basically the same situation as if you'd defined an inline function, and a **worse** situation than if you'd just used, say, a `static const int` or similar.

Comment: @jalf literature and references please.  That's not the way I learned it.

Comment: @DavidCowden: test it yourself. `#define FOO 10*(100+1000)`, and then `int main() { int i = FOO; }`. Run the preprocessor without compiling the code, and look at the result. It will **not** say `int i = 11000;`. It will say `int i = 10*(100+1000)`. And then, it is up to your compiler if it is going to evaluate that at compile-time (it probably will do that, but the point is, it's not the `#define` ensuring that. The `#define` just inserts the text, it does nothing to ensure the result is evaluated in any specific way

Answer (score 69, accepted):

All operators on `int`s return `int`.  So yes, `60 * 60 * 1000 / 1 * 1000 - 1` is an `int`.  But the expected result of 3599999999 is too big for an `int`, so the expression actually evaluates to -694967297 (assuming 32-bit `int` and two's complement).

This doesn't happen with a literal `3600000000` because integer literals larger than `INT_MAX` are of a type that *can* hold the full value.

Comment: "a type that can hold the full value" - IF such a type exists. There's no guarantee for literals that exceed `ULONG_MAX`.

Comment: Integer (as opposed to stack) overflow :)

Comment: Even `60 * 60 * 1000` may be too big for an `int`; seem my answer.

Answer (score 42):

60 * 60 * 1000 / 1 * 1000 - 1 = 3600000 * 1000 - 1, which overflows the int type, so the result can be anything (in your case it's negative, but it doesn't have to be).

To achieve what you want put ( ):

```
#define BIG_INTERVAL (60 * 60 * 1000)
#define SMALL_INTERVAL (1 * 1000)
```

Comment: +1 for suggesting parentheses - that explains the real issue - though avoiding macros would be even better advice.  Still, "overflows the int type, so it's negative" makes this sound like the former always implies the latter. Pedantic, but formally it's undefined behaviour for signed integral types and in practice it generally means you get garbage that might be positive or negative... here 3,600,000 * 1,000 happens to be <2^32 but >2^31 so it's negative on common platforms with 32-bit `int`s....

Answer (score 12):

Here's my test results:

```
60 * 60 * 1000 / 1 * 1000 will result to -694967296

(60 * 60 * 1000) / (1*1000) will result to 3600
```

There's a problem with your operation, the precedence of computations.

You might want to consider looking at the C++ operator precedence http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/126fe14k%28v=vs.80%29.aspx. You'll find the reason why the  result became -694967296 which I think effect of overflow.

Comment: @muntoo - Here, I explained it.

Answer (score 9):

If you use a compiler where int is 64 bits, you will find that the result of your expression is false.  If you use a compiler where int is 32 bits or 16 bits, your expression has undefined behaviour because overflow of signed ints doesn't have to wrap around.  Probably yours did just wrap around, but it doesn't have to.

3600000000 is a constant visible at compile time, so if int is only 32 bits then your compiler will have to choose long long (or just long if long is 64 bits).  So your other expression is evaluated with enough bits to avoid overflowing, and the result is correct.

Comment: I always thought negative wrapping is standard - is it actually undefined?

Comment: @mafutrct: C and C++ standards do not mandate anything on the representation of signed types, so there is no guarantee that you'll be wrapping around since 2-complement is not compulsory (and overflow of operations is undefined). For n-bit *signed* types, however, the standards mandates modulo 2^n arithmetic.

Comment: what compiler do you know of where int is 64 bits?

Comment: @Alexandre C. You probably mean "For n-bit *unsigned* types, however, ..."

Comment: @AlexandreC.: I see, thanks. So the C++ programs I wrote years ago contain yet another hack.

Comment: @Alexandre: That's not quite true.  C99 specifies that singed integers must be represented using either 2's-complement, 1s'-complement, or sign-and magnitude.  But the *representation* doesn't still doesn't mandate any particular behavior on signed overflow.

Answer (score 4):

Could be that you're overflowing the size of an int which is 2147m or so signed which means if you go over the representation for that becomes negative. As pointed out by other answers the division does nothing when expanded so surround the macro definitions with parentheses

Comment: approx. 2147 million , not 2.7 million (assuming 4 byte int)

Comment: Thanks, I really shouldn't answer questions while sleepy :P

Comment: It might be of interest to note that this probably happens for the OP because the internal representation uses [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), but overflow behavior in general is undefined.

Comment: @Maxpm you are completely correct as some compilers actually handle overflow of constant values by assigning it to -1 or some other value

Answer (score 2):

You are most likely going outside the valid range of values for a signed int - 3600000000 is quite a large number!

When this happens, the value will become the smallest negative value for the int data type.

This will result in your statement being true.

Answer (score 1):

Each of the arguments to that expression is an integer, so the result will be an integer.

Comment: Yes, they're integers.  More to the point, they're `int`s.  (The word `integer` covers a number of types, from `char` up to `long long`; `int' is a particular type, not *just* an abbreviation of `integer`.)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confused about how Macros work. You are not using the values from those macros but the equations themselves. I think this is were your confusion lies. I think you should parenthesis in your macros or not use macros.

Answer (score 0):

Something that I haven't seen anyone mention is that even fully parenthesizing the macro definitions doesn't completely solve the problem.

The question has:

```
#define BIG_INTERVAL 60 * 60 * 1000
```

(and the questioner acknowledges that the lack of parentheses is a problem).  But even with:

```
#define BIG_INTERVAL (60 * 60 * 1000)
```

each of the constants (60, 60, and 1000) is definitely representable as an int, but the product is 3600000, whereas the language only guarantees that `INT_MAX >= 32767`.

The language says that large integer constants are of a type big enough to hold their values (for example, `100000` can be either of type `int` or of type `long int`, depending on the ranges of those types), but it has no such rule for expressions, even constant expressions.

You can work around this like this:

```
#define BIG_INTERVAL (60L * 60L * 1000L)
```

but that makes it of type `long` even if it doesn't need to be.

As for the operator precedence issue, here's my favorite example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIX 1+5
#define NINE 8+1

int main(void)
{
    printf("%d * %d = %d\n", SIX, NINE, SIX * NINE);
    return 0;
}
```

The output, of course, is

```
6 * 9 = 42
```

(see Douglas Adams).